# How to resolve "JVM debug port -1 is in use." issue on RAD?

Tags: java, ibm-rad

I am getting "JVM debug port -1 is in use." error.
I am not even able to start the sever in "normal" mode. And that is the reason I can not even change the debugging port.

But the main question is what -1? How do I find it?

I have below links but none of them seem to have my problem.
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4592520/rad-jvm-debug-port-is-in-use)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20117457/jvm-debug-port-7779-is-in-use)
[Link3](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19528-01/819-4738/abgdm/index.html)

Comment: When talking about stuff like JVM, one should always mentioned the OS used. So, if you are on linux, use the command sudo killall java  and on windows, open task manager, and find the java-process and end its process-tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need to do is really just combining two answers from the previous posts you have already found.

**First apply a quick fix**: you are unable to start up the websphere instance because that debug port is already in use. To overcome that you need to shut down any other websphere instance on that machine for a short period of time. You can even kill rogue processes from command line if they appear to be hanging.

**Solve the real problem**: now that you will be able to start up the server normally follow the advice given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20118268/821786) and set a unique debug port for this instance so that you will never face this issue again, then do a restart. After this you are free to restart the rest of the instances you just stopped.

*Note: you may be in a situation where there is no other instance deployed on the affected machine. In this case the port is almost surely being used by a not-properly-stopped process of your own instance, in which case again `kill -9` will solve the problem.

Comment: Kill -9 which process?

Comment: The one that blocks that port. Look for existing websphere processes, or generally any suspicious java processes. You can also use standard unix commands like `lsof` or `netstat` to narrow your search.

Comment: With netstat I get below kind of output : Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
 TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1688. It does not help to identify the Java process running. It would be great if you could be little explanatory.

Comment: @Sam On windows, netstat -a -o -b will display the process id and below inside [ and ] will be the named of the executable that opened the port.  You must run this from a command line with admin priviledges because of the -b parameter.

Comment: There are lots of good answers on this topic, this one gives you at least three different options: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/126002/what-processes-are-using-which-ports-on-unix